# What do empty returns in the main function mean?

Tags: go

I copy-pasted the code from an API (https://api.magiceden.dev/). This code gets the link and prints a slice. Here's the code:

```
func main() {
    url := "https://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/wallets/6xX3z7uxTNB68izZW2GHKnzno49dizqeVVc5ncVzdjFM/activities?offset=0&limit=100"
    method := "GET"

    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, nil)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

I'm new to Go, and I know about empty return statements in other functions, but what is returned in main function? That's the question and I still haven't found the answer.

I tried googling it, but I couldn't find any info or examples of empty return statements in main function.

Comment: `return` works in `main` the _exact same way_ as it works in other functions. `but what is returned in main function?` Nothing.

Comment: @tkausl what does those return in the main function actually return? I'm confused and your comment actually makes nor sense or use

Comment: It returns _nothing_. It just returns.

Comment: See [Program execution](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Program_execution) and [Return statements](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Return_statements).

Answer (score 3):

When there is no return type in the function signature the `return` in such a function just stops the processing of the function at this point. No further statement are run then, but the registered `defer` functions are processed in the reverse order they have been registered.